# gradient in shadow box using tcolorbox

Tags: gradient, shadowbox

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}%
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[shadow={4mm}{-3mm}{0mm}{black!23!white},enhanced,colback=black!7,frame style=,title=Problem 1. Simulating the Luria-Delbr\"{u}ck Experiment over One Generation]
Write a program to simulate just one generation of the LD experiment - stochastically.  Simulate $C=500$ cultures each of which has $N=1000$ cells and $\mu=10^{-3}$, i.e.,  a very high mutation rate.   What is the distribution of resistant mutants that you observe across all the cultures?  Are they similar or dissimilar to each other?  Specify your measurement of $c(m)$, i.e., the number of cultures with m resistant mutants.  Is this distribution well fit by a Poisson distribution?  If so, what is the best fit shape parameter of the Poisson density function and how does that relate to the microscopic value of mutation you used to generate the output?  Finally, to what extent are the fluctuations ``large'' or ``small''?
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

I need to apply the `color gradient` for the `shadow color`, i.e., shadow starts from `black 23%` and ended with `white` color. Please advise.

I'm using `XeLaTeX` and `MikTeX2.9` in `Windows10`

Comment: Would a `drop fuzzy shadow=black!90` be better suited?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, your suggestion working fine, can you make your `comment` as `answer` for this post?

Comment: You're welcome! I converted the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `drop fuzzy shadow`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}%
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}%
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}%%

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,
  colback=black!7,
  frame style=,
  title=Problem 1. Simulating the Luria-Delbr\"{u}ck Experiment over One Generation,
  drop fuzzy shadow=black!80
]
Write a program to simulate just one generation of the LD experiment - stochastically.  Simulate $C=500$ cultures each of which has $N=1000$ cells and $\mu=10^{-3}$, i.e.,  a very high mutation rate.   What is the distribution of resistant mutants that you observe across all the cultures?  Are they similar or dissimilar to each other?  Specify your measurement of $c(m)$, i.e., the number of cultures with m resistant mutants.  Is this distribution well fit by a Poisson distribution?  If so, what is the best fit shape parameter of the Poisson density function and how does that relate to the microscopic value of mutation you used to generate the output?  Finally, to what extent are the fluctuations ``large'' or ``small''?
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]